# С чего начать изучать питон

Tags: python-3.x

С чего начать изучать питон? Где найти гайды? Я просто полный ноль в программировании, я знаю только логику кода и все. _. Я знаю основы питона но это основы основ)

Comment: С любого учебника.

Comment: А какой можете посоветовать?

Comment: ЛЮБОЙ, вы больше времени потратите решая что выбрать - в сети напишите питон учебник онлайн и читайте